# filtrar dataframes en pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe

he entrado hace poco con python-canvas y no consigo que me funcionen los filtros de un dataframe. Ninguno de ellos hace efecto, ni siquiera dan error. Os adjunto un codigo de ejemplo de los que he probado:

```
import pandas as pd

s1 = pd.read_csv('sudo1.csv')
su = pd.DataFrame(s1)
print (su)
filtro = [True,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False]
su[filtro]
```

existen 9 filas y despues del filtro siguen apareciendo todas, utilizo el ide pycharm y el so el ultimo ubuntu

Comment: Buen día, si alguna respuesta te fue útil no olvides aceptarla, de esa forma ayudas a otros usuarios a encontrar la solución a preguntas similares y al mismo tiempo ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas. [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen día,

Para poder aplicar los filtros debes utilizar alguna de las funciones [`pandas.DataFrame.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) o [`pandas.DataFrame.iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html). Te recomiendo leer la documentación para entender la diferencia entre ellas pero básicamente `loc` accede con los nombres de las etiquetas de las filas y las series y `iloc` con los índices.

Ejemplo genérico con `loc`

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]})
filtro = [True,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,True]
df['Col1'].loc[filtro]
```

Esto imprime:

```
0     1
9    10
Name: Col1, dtype: int64
```

Comment: import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]})
filtro = [True,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,True]
df['Col1'].loc[filtro]
print (df)

Answer (score 0):

tienes que indicar una condición que incluya el nombre de la columna por ejemplo:

Siendo brand una columna y Amazon el valor que se quiere buscar, en este caso excluir:

```
import pandas as pd
# leer el archivo y cargarlo en el dataframe df
df = pd.read_csv('data/Reviews.csv')
# contar la cantidad de filas que hay en el dataframe
df['brand'].count()
1597

# excluir del dataframe las filas que tengan Amazon como brand  y crear
# un nuevo dataframe df_filtered
df_filtered = df[df['brand']!='Amazon']]
# contar la cantidad de filas del nuevo dataframe
df_filtered['brand'].count()
12
```